# Laravel - why is node module loader referring to a node-sass version that is not on my site?

Tags: node.js, laravel

I am doing some development on my local environment (MAC Sierra), and when my site loads I keep getting this error:

```
throw new Error("Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (67)\nFor more information on which environments are supported please see:\nhttps://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.3\n
```

I have read about this error. I am running node v 8.2.1 and updated node-sass to 4.12 based on my operating system environment.

In my `node_modules` folder there is no node-sass folder with version 4.5.3. Even if I delete the `node-sass` folder I still get this error. If I clear cache I still get this error. I just can't figure out where in the laravel app this node-sass 4.5.3 would be getting loaded.

I have tried rebuilding node-sass. I have tried a dozen things suggested regarding this problem. But my app seems to nonetheless think I have `node-sass 4.5.3`...

Ideas?

thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should delete node_modules folder , packages-lock.json file then run :

```
npm cache clear --force 
npm install 
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: I followed those steps, but same result. It seems like there must be some other cache that Laravel is using and it just isn't seeing anything new. Quite a mystery. I am on a MAC. Maybe it is related to the fact that there is another node_modules folder on the computer.  That said, since I have node_modules at my site root I can't see why a system node_modules folder would play any role. Just don't know what on earth is going on...

Comment: I found that error hard coded in my app.js file in a throw new error function. Weird. Now I have to do some digging to see why on earth this is in the file! I think your answer is correct, just a weird case with my app, so upvoting :-)